# Switching back to previous user after "sudo -i" using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, root, sudo, sudoers

I want to add a super user to /etc/sudoers by running a script and then continuing installation. Therefore, I need to switch the user back to the original user from root after adding the user. Here is what I got:

```
...
current_user=$(whoami)
sudo -i
sudo echo "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
sudo su $current_user 
...
```

Unfortunately the last line does not work, since $current_user is null for some reason. Any guidance as to what might be the problem would be appreciated.

Best,

Comment: Use `exit` to return to the parent shell

Comment: Also, don't do this in the first place. Figure out a better way to do whatever it is that this `sudoers` change is supposed to achieve. Allowing your web user to run root commands without a password challenge seems like a great way to lose control of your system. Use `Cmnd_Alias` to provide access to only the commands you require, or have your web application speak through an API to a daemon that can only do what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo -i` is for interactive use, to run a simple command as root, you just add sudo in front of it. In this case, since we want to pipe to a file that requires elevated permissions, we should run the shell as sudo. The commands in the questions could be written as:

```
...
sudo bash -c 'echo "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers'
...
```

Comment: As the solution suggests, there is no need to switch users